# Unlimited number of tables getting produces

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 47; $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++)
    {
        echo "<td class=\"tableContents color3\"></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

When I execute it, it just keeps executing while it is supposed to stop execution after 47 loops.
Any ideas on what's wrong and any better methods to achieve the same thing?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting `$i` inside your inner loop each time.
It never increases to 47 in the outer loop.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - you override `$i` in the inner loop. Use `$j` or another different variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

for ($i=0;$i<=47;$i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0;$j<=11;$j++) {
        echo "<td class=\"tableContents color3\"></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Use 2 different index variables (i and j in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable in both the loops, so it will never be 47.

Answer (score 1):

```
<? for($i=0;$i<=47;$i++):?>
    <tr>
    <? for ($j=0;$j<=11;$j++):?>
        <td class="tableContents color3"></td>
    <? endfor;?>
    </tr>
<? endfor;?>
```

Comment: you'll have to balance between speed and readability, using the alternative way of writing you dont have to escape your `qoutes` or `double qoutes`